# Amine group - electron donating or withdrawing group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, amines

Is the amine group a donating or withdrawing group? I think it depends on resonance. If the amine group can participate in resonance, the amine group is inductively donating. Resonance depictions below.

[image]

Comment: You are right, when the amine group takes part in resonance through its free electron pair it donates elctrons - but not inductively but through conjugation. When it can't conjugatively use its electron pair the rather high electronegativity of $\ce{N}$ comes into play and the amine group exerts an inductive electron-withdrawing effect on neighboring carbon atoms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the atome of nitrogen participates through its free electron pair in resonance, the amine group plays the role of a donating group by conjugation. When it cannot participate in conjugation through resonance, the amine groupe plays the role of inductive electron-withdrawer group, due to the higher electronegativity of nitrogen atom compared to carbon atom.

When the amine group plays the role of electron donating group through conjugation, its inductive withdrawing effect (still existing) is weaker and masked by the first effect.